# Recognizing a PC in a school or university network

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, samba

I would like to use a Ubuntu server as NAS. I installed Ubuntu server and samba in the PC, and can connect via ssh using the IP-address. However, the pc is connected in a large network owned by the university and I was not allowed to use a static IP. I would like to know, whether there is a way to recognize the PC either by the mac address or any other means. Also, the file sharing works fine in linux PC and using WinSCP, but does not work through a windows PC. Is there any way to map the shared folder of Ubuntu server in Windows 10?

I would highly appreciate any comments or suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Use your own source of Internet (Hotspot modem that many ISPs offer) and ask for one that can have a static IP or use something like the DynDNS service to provide a static IP.

Comment: Is there any way to map the shared folder of Ubuntu server in Windows 10?    ..... On the same network, on the Linux box:   smb://ipofwindows/drivename   and connect. Give the credentials required. I do that here and it works.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your comments. For mapping the shared folder, I meant the other way around actually. I would like to map the shared folder of NAS in Windows machine.

Comment: You might be able to set up a Samba share in Ubuntu and map that way. It has been a while since I did that.   \\ipofUbntu\sambashare and authenticate with Ubuntu credentials.   https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-cofnigure-samba#2-installing-samba

Comment: Setup your own private network and piggy back off the university. That’s fine by buying your own router and plugging the “internet” port in to the university network and connecting the rest of your devices to the router. Now you’re secure from anyone on the university network and all your devices can access each other, unhindered.

Comment: Is your IP address _actually_ dynamic? Just because it's DHCP-issued does not mean it's going to change at random.